# How to calculate various results on the basis of various input values with one formula (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, variables, excel-formula, poisson

I am relatively new to Excel VBA that's why I have some problems. 
I have constructed a (Poisson-) matrix with range `"EB5:EV25"` where each cell contains a formula that basically (not only) multiplies two input values, e.g. they look like

```
=POISSON(0;$H$2;FALSE)*POISSON(0;$H$2;FALSE)
```

where `"$H$2"` and `"$H$2"` are my first two input values.

The results are presented in `"EB33:ED33"` where in each of the three cells the sum of a certain part of the matrix above is summed up.

Lets say the column with one of the input values is H and the column with the other input values is K (the values are in every 82th row). Thus for every 82th row of column H and K my matrix in `"EB5:EV25"` calculates results and presents them in `"EB33:ED33"`. This solution so far only allows for presenting the results of one pair of input variables at a time - I need to change the row of input variables in my matrix manually. 
However I don't finally want to present my results in `"EB33:ED33"` but in a different column, say `"BA:BC"`, 2 rows after the row that contains the input values (separately for each row of input values).

I have already tried out some code but I am not even able to work with input variables that are in different columns, neither does my code change the input values - for each row of input values the results are always the same (i does not change).

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("EB5:EV25")

For i = 3 To Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row Step 82
    rng.Replace "$" & i - 1, "$" & i
    Application.Calculate
    Range("EB33:ED33").Copy
        Cells(i + 1, 63).PasteSpecial xlValues
Next i

Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Would be great if anybody is able to help!

Comment: In the cells where you want to results to occur, you could use an offset formula to perform the calculations on the input variables from two rows above.

Comment: Seems to be pretty useful. Could you help me with this? As I am totally new to Excel VBA it is not that easy. My already existing code only refers to one input value in column 8 ("H") but actually I have got two columns of input values, say the other one is column 10 ("J"). With these input values from columns 8 and 10 I want to calculate in my matrix ("EB5:EV25") the results which need to be plotted in columns 63 until 65 (since there are 3 result values for each pair of input variables). Im not sure if original question was clear enough